# What is created by Class.new.new

Tags: ruby

```
Class.new.new
# => #<#<Class:0x44f3a2>:0xd7244e>
```

I am curious to know what is created. Is it an object of object? Any technical explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: an instance of your new class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `Class.new` you are creating a new class. In fact not only you can create classes via the common syntax:

```
class Bird
    def is
        "word"
    end
end
```

but you can also use `Class::new` like this:

```
Bird = Class.new do
    def is
        "word"
    end
end
```

In the above example you can run `Bird.new.is` and it will return `"word"` just like in the first example.
It is useful to create anonymous classes or classes that you can rename at your will.
In your case:

```
Class.new.new
```

By simply calling `Class.new` you are creating a new anonymous class with no custom methods or instance variables which is then later instantiated via the second `new` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow it through in the console:

```
irb(main):011:0> c = Class.new
=> #<Class:0x000000028245e0>
```

`c` is a new class.

```
irb(main):012:0> c.new
=> #<#<Class:0x000000028245e0>:0x0000000282a170>
```

Calling `c.new` returns you a new instance of the new class you just created.

Answer (score 1):

`Class.new` creates and returns `Class` instance (which is class). If you call on it `new` again, previously created class will be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_class = Class.new # makes a new class which is a subclass of Object
my_instance = my_class.new # makes a new instance object of the class
```